# How to access and modify contacts in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have found a new contacts API in Windows 8: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

However I am unable to find out how to list all contacts and add or delete a contact.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Contact Picker](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Contact-Picker-App-sample-fc6677a1) sample.  You can't just go modify contacts, you have to have the user select them for you first.  This is done with the pickSingleContactAsync() method.  This gets you a ContactInformation object which you can query or modify.

Comment: The Contact Picker example does not show me my contacts, but rather some hardcoded contacts in json, see last lines: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Contact-Picker-App-sample-fc6677a1/sourcecode?fileId=43629&pathId=809654564

Comment: You should be able to use that with any contact provider on the system though.

Comment: Could you please give me a hint how can I use ContactPicker with other contact providers?

Comment: You cannot modify a contact through pickSingleContactAsync() they are all read only properties.

Answer (score 2):

**Contact  Lets your app create a new contact. Available only if your app uses the Contact contract.**

**PickMultipleContactsOperation  Launches the user interface of the Contact Picker to select multiple contacts.**

**PickSingleContactOperation  Launches the user interface of the Contact Picker to select a single contact.**

These three classes and/or methods will do everything you want except delete a contract, which I would hope is not exposed to an application.

Remember the documentation and API is not finished.

Comment: How I can create and save a new contact? What do you mean be Contact contract? Could you post short few lines sample how to modify and save a contact?